# Capturing Screenshot of Chromium-based Browser (e.g. Chrome) results in Black Screen

Tags: screenshot, chromium

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of a minimized chromium window with https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick. But all chromium based browsers end up as black and won't show. It works for all other windows like notepad and it works.[image: notepad window]

But when I try on a chromium based browser I get results like this. [image: Microsoft Edge]

I believe the issue is that it renders differently and i tried disabling gpu and direct x with arguments but it still didn't work.
`cmd.exe /c start chrome.exe --no-sandbox --allow-no-sandbox-job --disable-3d-apis --disable-gpu --disable-d3d11 --user-data-dir=`

Please do not respond with a method that brings the window to front then minimizes it again, thanks.

Comment: You are missing your code in the question

Comment: @Cleptus Yes sorry. I have fixed it now. I'm using his code https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick

Comment: So you do not want a solution that brings forward a windows, screen captures it and minimizes it again... But you are using a code that does exactly that. Maybe you should search for a different code to begin with. In the "How to capture" section of the linked article it says "_I tried to make the window back to normal and capture it then, and then minimize it again;_"

Comment: @Cleptus This does not bring forward the window. It uses printwindow, i have tried this with notepad as you saw while it being minimized and it didn't bring forward it.